# Can the list of SQLSTATEs be retrieved using SQL?

Tags: postgresql

Can the list of [PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) also be found in [System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html), [Information Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/information-schema.html), [System Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/views-overview.html), or somewhere else (using a query e.g. in psql)?

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: What do you need that list for? It should be available online, if that's suitable.

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether it's easily possible to generate a decent [language definition for GtkSourceView](https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/tree/master/data/language-specs). One where also `0A000`, `pg_catalog`, and `search_path` are recognized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to ask a Postgres server for the full list of SQLSTATEs.

The Postgres build process actually generates its C definitions for the error codes (as well as the HTML documentation) from this machine-readable file:

https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;hb=HEAD;f=src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt;a=blob_plain

Your best option is probably to fetch the file and parse it yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, from their [GitHub mirror](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgres/postgres/master/src/backend/utils/errcodes.txt)